# Can I tell Lucene.net not to create files over a certain size?

Tags: lucene.net

I have an upload limit on file sizes of 100MB but my index files are coming out larger than that. Is there an option somewhere I can set so that at a specific file size the index will spill out into a secondary file?

Comment: Please add a comment when down voting so the question can be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of. From [Java Lucene FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#Is_there_a_way_to_limit_the_size_of_an_index.3F):

> Is there a way to limit the size of an index?
>
> This question is sometimes brought up because of the 2GB file size
>   limit of some 32-bit operating systems.
>
> This is a slightly modified answer from Doug Cutting:
>
> The easiest thing is to use IndexWriter.setMaxMergeDocs().
>
> If, for instance, you hit the 2GB limit at 8M documents set
>   maxMergeDocs to 7M. That will keep Lucene from trying to merge an
>   index that won't fit in your filesystem. It will actually effectively
>   round this down to the next lower power of Index.mergeFactor.
>
> So with the default mergeFactor set to 10 and maxMergeDocs set to 7M
>   Lucene will generate a series of 1M document indexes, since merging 10
>   of these would exceed the maximum.